# Magento2 You must have installed GD library with --with-jpeg-dir=DIR option

Tags: magento2

I am using windows system with Xammp Server and i have uncommented line in php.ini (extension=php_gd2.dll) the php_gd2.dll will present in xammp/php/ext  but still getting an error like You must have installed GD library with --with-jpeg-dir=DIR option.

PHP Version :7.0.2
Magento Version :2.2.2